# Are not send transactions from coinbase account

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

i have a Ethereum-Wallet with 2 accounts. Transactions from first account(Main account (Etherbase)) not sending but incoming transactions working correctly. 
EtherWallet output:

```
[2016-10-11 10:57:49.034] [INFO] (ui: wallet) - EVENT LOG:  { '0': 'The transaction from Main account (Etherbase) to SE couldn\'t be successfully executed.' }
```

Sending via geth also does not work.
Second account works normal.
What could be the problem?